# How to compress code of html,css and js files

Tags: html

Suppose I have following html code

```
<span style="display: inline">Hello Wo</span>
<span style="display: none;"></span>
<span style="display: inline">rld</span>
```

Now what I want , when end user try to view the source code , above content should look like this

```
<span style="display: inline">Hello Wo</span><span style="display: none;"></span<span style="display: inline">rld</span>
```

Same should happen with js and css code.

Thanks in advance :)

**Edit:**
For security reason, I want the source code to become messy before user tries to  view it.

Comment: which IDE are you using?

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/MinifyResources ..will be useful..

Comment: A software that I love is called «Prepros» https://prepros.io/, using the free version is enough and it minify your CSS, SASS and JS file. It doesn't minify your HTML but still.

Answer (score 2):

I think you try to minify your code, it's a widely used process in web projects: 
To do those tasks, you could use tools called tasks runners.

Here is two examples of tool you could use:

[grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) or [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/)

**Edit** :

A gulpfile.js file example to minify your html:

```
// including plugins
var gulp = require('gulp')
, minifyHtml = require("gulp-minify-html");

// task
gulp.task('minify-html', function () {
    gulp.src('./Html/*.html') // path to your files
   .pipe(minifyHtml())
   .pipe(gulp.dest('path/to/destination'));
});
```

(Sample from : [julienrenaux.fr](http://julienrenaux.fr/2014/05/25/introduction-to-gulp-js-with-practical-examples/))

I Hope it may help